vk provider Auth.js v5 Next.js 14 Code challenge method error
I'm trying to add oauth using Vk provider.
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import Vk from "next-auth/providers/vk"



export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
    pages: {
        signIn: "/auth/login",
    },
    providers: [
        Vk,
        Vk({
            clientId: process.env.AUTH_VK_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.AUTH_VK_SECRET
        }),
    ]
})

And I'm getting an error {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Code challenge method is unsupported"}
I searched and there was a bug report https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/9898
that authorization params include "code_challenge_method":"S256" and by removing it the problem should be fixed but there are no info in the new documentation and old one has only the one sentence about default code_challenge_method and no information on how to change it. i tried manually but nothing helped
authorization: {
        codeChallengeMethod: 'plain'
    }


You can disable checks in NextAuth options like this:

But next you will face another problem, which i try to resolve now.

Hi, Vladislav! Did you resolve the issue with VK provider? I was faced with the fact that it does not work at all. Now the authorization goes through https://id.vk.com/authorize and probably according to different rules (https://id.vk.com/about/business/go/docs/ru/vkid/latest/vk-id/connection/start-integration/auth-flow-web). This provider may need a complete refactoring.

@Degibons Hi! I spend some time, but don't get any result. After that i look at the Lucia and make decission to write my own auth based on source code of Lucia. But you can use Lucia as is and it will works fine. Lucia did have almost the same providers. Cheers.
